# How to estimate face pose from 5 face landmarks in dlib ?

Tags: python, c++, dlib, pose-estimation

I saw recently the 5 point landmarking model from dlib: https://github.com/davisking/dlib-models 
I am instereing to use it to pose estimation, but I do not find the function in dlib that perform it. 
My question does it exist in dlib (C++, Python)?
If not, could you suggest efficient and small time consuming pose estimation algorithm and/or open sources from 5 point that are provided by dlib ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to get started:

http://www.morethantechnical.com/tag/head-pose/

OpenCV has a python wrapper so you can use it directly in your code.